# How can I add titile in viewforheadersection?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, header, title

Here is the full code.

```
let sections: [String] = ["Cleaning","Computer Repair", "Electircity", "Painting", "Plumbing"]

let sectionImages: [UIImage] = [picutre1, picture2, picture3, picture4]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.image = sectionImages[section]
    let headerView = UIView()
    headerView.addSubview(imageView)

    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true   
    imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
    imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true

    return headerView
}
```

How can I add title in header ?

And, is there another way to set the images autot layout?

Comment: You can make your custom header by adding view in `xib`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = sectionImages[section]

        let titleLabel = UILabel()
        titleLabel.text = sections[section]
        titleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: .bold)
        titleLabel.textAlignment = .left

        let headerView = UIView()
        headerView.addSubview(imageView)
        headerView.addSubview(titleLabel)

        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
        imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true

        titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        titleLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        return headerView
    }
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXKm3.jpg)

Comment: The code is working, but I have a little problem. Images and text in the center how to take it to the left

Comment: I tried this code. It's working fine in my project. Can you add a screenshot of it?

Answer (score 0):

Add UILabel to your custom header view

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.image = sectionImages[section]
    let headerView = UIView()
    headerView.addSubview(imageView)

    //Title
    var yourLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
    yourLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 20) // Change the frame based on your needs
    yourLabel.text = "test label"
    headerView.addSubview(yourLabel)

    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true   
    imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
    imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true

    return headerView
}
```